# Cannot read STDOut from Process that is running in background

Tags: c#, linux, process, bluetooth, .net-core

So, under Linux I have to connect to a bluetooth device via the command `rfcomm connect hci0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, which starts a bluetooth connection, but has to remain running in order to stay connected.

I have to write everything as an .NET Core Program

Running the command outputs the following lines after a few seconds:
`Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on channel 1
Press CTRL-C for hangup`

From that Output I have to get the `/dev/rfcomm0` part, so I can read it with a `SerialPortReader`, and if something goes wrong, like, let's say there is no more data incoming, I have to kill the process and start anew, until I have a good connection.

Now my logic is something like this:

```
while(!Terminate)
{
   string port = Connect();
   ReadData(port);
   BTProcess.Kill();
}
```

Don't bother with the `ReadData(port);` function, as my program never even comes near that.

The `Connect()` looks something like this:

```
while (!Connected)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Configuring Process");
    BTProcess = new Process();
    BTProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "rfcomm";
    BTProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "connect hci0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
    BTProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    BTProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    Console.WriteLine("Starting Process");
    BTProcess.Start();

    StreamReader reader = _BTProcess.StandardOutput;

    bool done = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Reading STDOUT now.");
    while (!done) // EDIT: If I do the while with !reader.EndOfStream then it won't even enter into the loop
    {
        Console.Write("-");
        int c = reader.Read(); // Program stops in this line

        if(c != -1)
        {
            port += (char)c;
        }

        Console.Write(c);
        if (c == 0)
        {
            port = "";
            done = true;
            _BTProcess.Kill();
        }
        if (/* String Contains Logic blabla */)
        {
            port = /* The /dev/rfcomm0 stuff */
            Connected = true;
            done = true;
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
return port;
```

I did check already if the Output isn't redirected to like STDErr or something, but no, it is 100% written in STDOut.

I have already tried a logic with like an EventHandler that handles StandardOutput Events, and a logic where I read it asynchronously, but both with no success. All had the same problem, they all block at the `Read();` function. My guess is that maybe the internal buffer doesn't get flushed correctly.

Maybe someone here knows an answer to my problem.
P.S.: I know my code isn't the best or most optimized, but it should nevertheless work, as I have tried it already with another blocking command under Windows and it worked.

Thanks in advance for every help I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by simply not running the command directly, because that throws buffer problems, so I now don't run the command `rfcomm connect hci0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, instead I run `stdbuf -o0 rfcomm connect hci0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, to avoid buffering problems.